# Incorrect Variable output with Vector Class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, vector, max

My output for the call to the temporary array size wont correctly output. It resizes as according, but I can't get the MAX to display the new value of the new array. My error is within the Resize function within the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


class VectorClass {



private:
    int * Vector;//This will be our resizeable array
    int Size; //Keep track of vector current size
    int MAX=10;
    int growth = 5;
    int num;
    int Resize(int growth, int MAX);


public:

    VectorClass(int growth, int Size);
    ~VectorClass();
    int AddItem(int num);   
    void RemoveItem();
    void Print(void);

};

VectorClass::VectorClass(int growth, int Size)
{

    Size = 10;
    growth = 5;

    Vector = new int[Size];



}

VectorClass::~VectorClass()
{


    cout << "Destructor was called." << endl;

}

//Will insert num into the vector at the current open position
int VectorClass::AddItem(int num)

{


    Vector[Size] = num;
    Size++; //Indicate that there isnt as much free space

    if (Size == MAX)
    {
        Resize(Size, MAX);
    }
    Print();

    return num;
}


//Get rid of the most recently added item
void VectorClass::RemoveItem()
{


    Size--; //Tricks the vector into one fewer elements in it it currently does
    Print();


}

int VectorClass::Resize(int growth, int MAX)
{
    cout << "Array is full! Resizing the Array!" << endl;

    //Step 1: make a copy
    int * temp = new int[MAX]; //Make a new array, same size as exiting array

                               //loop that copies the original into the copy
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = Vector[i];
    }

    //Step 2: Delete the original
    delete[] Vector; //Deletes all elements in the array Vector from the Heap

                     //Step 3: Make a bigger vector
    Vector = new int[MAX + growth];

    //Step 4: Reverse the copy  and record the size change
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        Vector[i] = temp[i];
    }
    MAX = MAX + growth;

    //Step 5: Delete the copy
    delete[] temp;

    cout << "Resize was called.\n" << endl;

    return MAX;
}

void VectorClass::Print()
{
    cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i< Size; i++)
    {
        cout << Vector[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Size = " << Size << "\tMAX = " << MAX << "\t Growth = " << growth << endl << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
}

int main(void)
{



    VectorClass V(5,10);


    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        int x = rand();

        V.AddItem(x);

    }



    //Print the Vector #1
    V.Print();


    //Delete 2 Items
    V.RemoveItem();
    V.RemoveItem();



    //Add 9 random Numbers      
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        int x = rand();

        V.AddItem(x);

    }

    //Print the Vector
    V.Print();







    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you post code here, please consider removing all the consecutive blank lines. With all of those blank lines, you add needless scrolling to see the code and I think it hurts readability of the question (you have 5 pages of code!).

Comment: sorry about that. I've altered this code a few times

Comment: Your constructor makes no sense.  You ignore the parameters passed, and you have an initial size (rather than just initial capacity) without specifying initial values.

Comment: Also, (different spin on peroket's answer) your AddItem assumes that `Size<MAX` (on entry to AddItem) and has undefined behavior when that was not true.  But your constructor makes that immediately not true, which peroket described as a bug in AddItem and I described as a bug in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Several things are wrong with you code. The first one, probably not the one you care about most, is that you never free the memory. You should do it in your destructor, or even better use a `std::unique_ptr` to handle your memory.

Now, i believe you are yourself confused about your own variables. I see that you possess a variable member named `num` that you never use. Even worse, you have a parameter in `AddItem` with the same name. Are you sure it does what you want? The same is true for `growth`. I would advise you to name your member variable differently, so that you know what they are quickly. I prefixe them with "m_" for example, but you can do as you wish.
You do not need to declare your function parameters inside your class. Only in the function prototype.

Then, in your `AddItem` function, you use your variable `Size` to determine where to add the new element, but you initialize your array with it too, which means that not only you do not add your elements at the beginning of your array, you try to write them in memory you do not own!

I could continue for a long time. I am sorry but it only appears to me that you do not know C++ at all. You should go learn the basics again, and maybe start with an easier project to begin your C++ learning.

Good luck :-)